# Triceratops head action figure?

Tags: object-identification

In the early 80s, there was a series of toys that I recall were similar to [Masters of the Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masters_of_the_Universe#Early_action_figures_and_comics) (although probably lower quality). I think that many of them were based on Greek mythology. The one that I had had a triceratops head. I think that his head and torso were red, but the arms and legs were yellow. He came with a black sword. I think one or two other figures in the series had animals heads, but the rest just had normal human heads. Was this from any notable series, or was it just a MotU knock-off?

Note: definitely not Triceraton from Ninja Turtles. The figure that I'm thinking is older by at least a few years, did not have a tail, and did not come with any guns or futuristic weapons.

Edit: Maybe "Galaxy Warriors", "Lost World of the Warlord", or "The Warrior Beasts", although I don't see the specific figure that I had.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This appears to be from [The Warrior Beasts](http://5point5figures.com/warrior-beasts/) by Remco. Apparently the figure's name was [Guana](https://www.figurerealm.com/actionfigure?action=actionfigure&id=17462&figure=guana). None of them seem to be based on Greek mythology, so I must have conflated this with another series. Possibly [Lost World of the Warlord](http://www.action-figures.ca/lost_world_warlord.htm) (which was also from Remco).